# scheduling muliple tasks with newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

If i schedule multiple tasks for ScheduledExecutorService , but i have made sure that there can be only thread to execute all the tasks, would each task be executed sequentially?

For eg: what happens in below scenario

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable{void run(){....}}, 6000,6000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable{void run(){....}}, 6000,6000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the javadoc:

> Creates an Executor that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) **Tasks are
>   guaranteed to execute sequentially**, and no more than one task will
>   be active at any given time. Unlike the otherwise equivalent
>   newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be
>   reconfigurable to use additional threads.

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)

Comment: Fyi, link mentioned is not available.